# python numpy.single gives different result when using out parameter

Tags: python, numpy, casting, floating-point, precision

I am trying to cast from a double precision array to single precision. To optimize on space I tried using the out argument so that numpy doesn't allocate additional space.  However the results seem different for the two version of the call

```py
import numpy as np

doubleArr = np.zeros((10000,10000), dtype=np.double)
doubleArr[0,0] = 1e-30
singleArr = np.single(doubleArr)
print ("%.40f"%singleArr[0,0]) 
singleArr = np.zeros((10000,10000), dtype=np.single)
np.single(doubleArr, out=singleArr)
print ("%.40f"%singleArr[0,0])
```

The results are

```
0.0000000000000000000000000000010000000032
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Is the usage of "out" parameter incorrect?

Comment: In my `numpy` version `np.single` (`np.float32`) doesn't take an `out` parameter.

Comment: @hpaulj is correct--`np.float32` does not take an `out` parameter. In old versions of numpy, unknown keyword arguments to `np.float32` (aka `np.single`) were *ignored*.  For example, in version 1.8.0, I can write `np.float32(123, foobar="plate of shrimp")` and no error is generated.   I don't know when this was fixed. Which version of numpy  are you using?  You can check with `import numpy as np; print(np.__version__)`

Comment: I am using '1.17.4' . So essentially, the outparameter is being ignored?

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the cast without creating additional allocation?

Comment: Yes, `out` is ignored.  If you've already created the array, you can simply assign the values: `singleArr[...] = doubleArr`.

Comment: I tried that. It seems to create additional memory, at least thats what memory_profiler reports.

Answer (score 0):

This mystery is resolved. Numpy.ctypes when calling c routines creates a bunch of memory for c-python interoperation. This memory doesn't get collected immediately which results in blow up in total memory usage. The solution is to use gc.collect when under memory pressure.